# Should I configure my integration tests as a continuous build or a nightly build?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

In my project we have a set of integration test fixtures which are typically slow compared to the unit test fixtures. Typically it takes close to 3 hours to complete the integration test run.

My question is, should I be configuring my integration test run as a continuous build (which obviously depends upon my continuous build of unit test fixtures and runs after that) or should I be configuring it as a nightly build?

If I configure it as a nightly build, will that be widening my feedback cycle?

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: "(which obviously depends upon my continuous build of unit test fixtures and runs after that)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your integration tests run for 3 hours then surely this is choking up one of your agents for all this time which could otherwise be used for other check-in builds?

When our check-in build started to take over 30 minutes we took measures to reduce this back to under 10 mins. The fundamentals we decided on were: With the changes, does it compile? and does it pass all unit tests? Other chained builds were executed in the same way. This keeps the feedback cycle sharp for core mistakes. The other build features were pushed back to a nightly, failures of which were then addressed in the morning.

I personally think a task that takes 3 hours should definitely be pushed to a nightly. This is  unless you have a large agent pool which wouldn't dry up.

Perhaps another alternative is to kick off the integration tests build a couple of time a day, perhaps midday and evening.